# Run function asynchronously in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-apps-script, promise, slack-api

I'm making a Slack bot that calls a GAS function. Everything is working except Slack shows an error message because it only waits 3 seconds for a response when calling an API.

Can anyone help me to work out how to run everyDay2 asynchronously so that I can return the response before it's finished. I've tried Promises and callbacks but I can't solve it.

```
function doPost(e){

  const promise = new Promise(everyDay2);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('thinking...');

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Google Apps Script V8 engine support Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578224/does-google-apps-script-v8-engine-support-promise)

Comment: I tried that. If I do this:

    `let asyncFunction = async function() { everyDay2() };`
    `return ContentService.createTextOutput('thinking...');`

Obviously `everyDay2` is never called.

When I do this:


    `let asyncFunction = async function() { everyDay2() };`
    `asyncFunction();`
    `return ContentService.createTextOutput('thinking...');`


It seems like `asyncFunction` runs synchronously and the response is sent too late. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promises doesn't work. Use [triggers instead](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#afterdurationmilliseconds):

```
function doPost(e) {
  runAfter1s('everyDay2');
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('thinking...');
}

const runAfter1s = func =>
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(func)
    .timeBased()
    .after(1000)
    .create();
```

Make sure to delete the created trigger inside `everyDay2` after being triggered.