# App-script runtime error "Exceeded maximum execution time" in workspace addon

Tags: google-apps-script, quota, google-workspace-add-ons

*Problem:*

I am getting the error **Exceeded maximum execution time** after about 45 seconds.

*Expected behaviour:*

The function should run for 6 Minutes. After that duration I would expect an error.
I checked up the current quota limits here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

*My setup for testing:*

I tried to remove all code and just have a single function "runFor6Min()" which only executes:

```
Utilities.sleep(6000 * 10)
```

I assume that the function should be treated as a **Script runtime** (6 Min) and not as a **Custom function runtime** (30s) e.g. a custom function within a Google Sheet.

Any ideas what else I could try?

Appended appsscript.json
[image]

Comment: Show your appsscript.json

Comment: Updated the question ... what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: For future reference, always include data as plain text and not as image(some would like to actually test your issue and it's impossible to copy/paste a image).  And provide all the data as a [mcve]. For eg, your question is missing  the connection between `onDefaultHomePageOpen` and `runFor6mins()`, which is where the actual issue is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `CardService` to call server side functions,  you're limited to 30s of execution time as written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/actions#callback_functions):

> Warning: The Apps Script Card service limits callback functions to a maximum of 30 seconds of execution time. If the execution takes longer than that, your add-on UI may not update its card display properly in response to the Action.

Comment: This is probably the root cause - thanks for pointing me into the right direction. Do you have any idea on how to trigger a longer running function from a Card Service Action?

Comment: @Vinz You can try setting up a trigger like https://stackoverflow.com/a/62807671. But you won't be getting the output of that function directly. You may ask a new question regarding this.