# Appscript How to trigger onChange when editing a sheet from a script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm using doPost() in my appscript to handle a elementor form submission.
Once i add the fields in the sheet i need to make an API call.
So i want to call my doApi() function with a onChange trigger.
Only nothing happens...

If i call doApi in doPost i think it timesout on the client side and the elementor form fails with a False negative.

I guess using setValue doesn't trigger the onChange or onEdit triggers as they only work for user input when the document is open, but not when a change is done by a function call in AppScript.

Any clues how i could Hack onChange to be triggered by the onPost new line insert ?

```
const doPostCell = [2,15]
const apiCell = [2,16]
const editCell = [2,18]
function onEdit(){
  modifyTriggerCell(editCell)
}

// create a new contact in rentman
function DoApi () {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const configSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('configuration');
  const configRowData = configSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  // We get the diferent ID's from the second line (index[1])
  const configRow = configRowData[1]
  Logger.log(configRow)
  
  const token = configRow[0]
  modifyTriggerCell(apiCell)


  return 
}



function modifyTriggerCell(e) {
  const datatSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Formulaire elementor');
  const values = datatSheet.getDataRange().getValues()[datatSheet.getLastRow() - 1]
  const counterCell = datatSheet.getRange(e[0], e[1])
  const counterCellVal = counterCell.getValue()
  counterCell.setValue(counterCellVal + 1)
}
```

Comment: There no triggers that fire on edits caused by scripts or forumulas with the exception of some import formulas and that is an onChange with a type of "OTHER"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no trigger works with appscript function calls i found out with this post i could build a trigger so that the doPost function could resolve and answer to the form that wont timeout thank to that. And my doApi function is executed 1second later.
[Run function asynchronously in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806366/run-function-asynchronously-in-google-apps-script)

So now my script looks like this :

```
const runAfter1s = func =>
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(func)
    .timeBased()
    .after(1000)
    .create();

/**
* this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
* Not used but required.
*/
function doGet( e ) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput( "Yepp this is the webhook URL, request received" );
}

// Webhook Receiver - triggered with form webhook to pusblished App URL.
function doPost( e ) {
  if(e){
    var params = JSON.stringify(e.parameter);
    params = JSON.parse(params);
    insertToSheet(params);
  }

  modifyTriggerCell(doPostCell)

  runAfter1s('doApi')

  // HTTP Response
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput( "post request received" );
}
```

My only question left is on how to delete the trigger as stated in the original post ?

> Make sure to delete the created trigger inside everyDay2 after being
> triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily enough i don't have any other triggers so i can just loop to delete any that was create. Else they stay as deactivated and pile up so better clean that mess up.

```
   var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
```